# Reusing annotations by creating meta annotations

Tags: annotations, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am just wondering whether we can create a meta-annotation and reuse it everywhere. For example, I have an annotation like so:

```
@QueueBinding(value = @Queue, exchange = @Exchange(value = "MY_FANOUT_EXCHANGE", type = ExchangeTypes.FANOUT))
```

I need to use it in multiple places. I just want to simplify it something like:

```
@MyFanoutExchangeBinding = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue, exchange = @Exchange(value = "MY_FANOUT_EXCHANGE", type = ExchangeTypes.FANOUT))
```

and then use the `@MyFanoutExchangeBinding` on methods everywhere. If I understand annotations correctly, its not possible. Or is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta annotations won't work in this context since the `@RabbitListener` `bindings` property is a `QueueBinding[]` and annotations don't have inheritance.

To implement it would need a customized `RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` but, since it can't be done in a generic way, I don't think it can be part of the framework, at least in the way you describe.

We might be able to reduce the boilerplate in some other way though; feel free to open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and we can take a look at what might be possible.

**EDIT**

After receiving the [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-597) I thought about it some more and you can achieve your desired results using a custom listener annotation, meta-annotated with `@RabbitListener` ...

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
        value = @Queue,
        exchange = @Exchange(value = "test.metaFanout", type = ExchangeTypes.FANOUT, autoDelete = "true")))
public @interface MyAnonFanoutListener {
}

public static class MetaListener {

    @MyAnonFanoutListener
    public void handle1(String foo) {
        ...
    }

    @MyAnonFanoutListener
    public void handle2(String foo) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Each listener will get an anonymous, auto-delete, queue bound to the fanout exchange.

Comment: Is it possible to use meta annotations for @RabbitListener and pass down the "key" attribute for the nested @QueueBinding?  Basically want to share boilerplate RabbitListener / QueueBinding definitions for a topic exchange but allow the user to pass in the routing key to the custom annotation which would then be set on the RabbitListeners QueueBinding

Comment: No; you can't do that; the only thing you can do is `key="${some.property}"` and set a property - but you'd be limited to one per application. It would be better to declare the queue and binding as `@Bean`s instead of using `@QueueBinding`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply